# Is there any way to highlight/modal component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm not sure how to search this. I'm trying to highlight banners like a modal. is there any package or example for this? like when the user clicks next button shipment banner will show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material-UI 5 uses a Popper component. Their documentation has great examples! Alternatively you can create your own.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "onboarding" or "tour" libraries.
For example, [React Joyride](https://react-joyride.com/).